# ¿Como paso las fechas de un form a otro?

Tags: jquery

Tengo un formulario donde el usuario introduce dos fechas y un boton listar que lista los movimientos de ventas:

```html
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
 <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">POR FECHA</h3>  
                       </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body" style="background-color: azure;color:black ;">
                        <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-2">
                        <p>FECHA DESDE</p>  </div><div class="col-sm-2"><input id="fechad" type="date"/></div>
                       
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <p>FECHA HASTA</p></div><div class="col-sm-2"><input id="fechah" type="date"/></div>
                      
                       <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?controller=reporte&action=fecha">LISTAR</a>
                       </div> </div>
                      

</div></div></div>
```

El problema es que quiero redirigir con href al usuario a otra pagina con la tabla de movimientos, entonces en un js que incluyo en dicha pagina tngo la funcion listar:

```js
function listar(){
          fechadesde=$("#fechad").val();
   fechahasta=$("#fechah").val();
  
        $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/reporte/procesoReporte.php",
            data: { "accion": "fecha","fechad":fechadesde,"fechah":fechahasta}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){demas codigo
```

Pero como guardo esas dos fechas al cargar la vista de listar por fechas para pasarselas a la funcion listar?

Es decir tengo lo siguiente:

```html
  <script src="views/modules/reporte/reportefecha.js"></script>
<div class="row">

<div class="row">
<table id="resultado">
<caption>Catalogo de articulos</caption>
<thead>
<tr> <th>COD.:</th> <th>DESCRIPCION</th> <th>MARCA</th>
            <th>CATEGORIA</th> <th>P/U</th><th>Accion</th>
            </tr></thead>
            <tbody>
            
            </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Pero las fechas no llegan a esa instancia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que hacerlo usando javascript asi:

```js
$(".btn-primary").click(function () {
  fechadesde=$("#fechad").val();
   fechahasta=$("#fechah").val();
   
   window.location.href = "index.php?controller=reporte&action=fecha&fechad=" + fechadesde + "&fechah=" +fechahasta;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
 <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">POR FECHA</h3>  
                       </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body" style="background-color: azure;color:black ;">
                        <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-2">
                        <p>FECHA DESDE</p>  </div><div class="col-sm-2"><input id="fechad" type="date"/></div>
                       
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <p>FECHA HASTA</p></div><div class="col-sm-2"><input id="fechah" type="date"/></div>
                      
                       <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0);">LISTAR</a>
                       </div> </div>
                      

</div></div></div>
```

Luego puedes obtener los parametros asi:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('fechad');
```

Comment: Ese window.location.href debe estar entre la function success() porque la primera accion es un POST.  procesoReporte.php procesa el data y revuelve a success(data) { } ..  Lo que revuelve está en data y puede incluir las fechas.

Comment: Y como tomo las variables fechad y fechah que pasaste como parametro en la url? Es decir en el otro archivo

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.