# Intercambio de información entre dos páginas

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo dos páginas a la cuál llamaremos Página1 y Página2. Pretendo enviar un folio de la Página1 a la Página2 insertandolo en un input de tipo texto.

En la Página1 tengo un procedimiento que al dar click en una tabla me recupera el folio de la columna 1, dicho folio es el que pretendo insertarlo en la Página2 de tipo Popup. Mi código en javascript es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        var table = $("#example").DataTable();

        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function()
        {
            var Folio = table.row(this).data();
            $("#folioBlotter").val(Folio[0]);
            var FOLIO = $("#folioBlotter").val()
            // window.open('blotter.modificar.php', 'Modificar', "width=1000, height=500, top=85, left=50", true);
            myWindow = window.open("blotter.modificar.php", "Blotter Modificar", "width=1000, height=500, top=85, left=50");
            myWindow.document.write(document.getElementById("modifpNumFolio").innerHTML = FOLIO);
        });
    });
```

Alguien sabe como puedo enviarlo a mi input con ID modifNumFolio

Gracias

Comment: Chequea esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/283365/como-paso-las-fechas-de-un-form-a-otro/283368#283368

Comment: alanfcm gracias, me sirvio bastante, Ya logré enviar la información. Pero tengo una nueva pregunta, cuando la coloco en el input con un <?php echo $Folio ?> la inserta con tabulaciones visualizando fuera del rango del input. Hay manera de enviar los datos sin esa tabulación?

Comment: Intenta con `<?php echo trim($Folio) ?>`

Comment: Gracias, lo coloque como indicas y lo sigue enviando al final con tabulaciones, incluso lo intenté aplicar desde el $_GET pero tampoco los elimina